# What is precise definition of "monomial curve" in affine $e$-space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

What is precise definition of *monomial curve* in affine $e$-space ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A curve is said to be monomial curve if $~\exists~$ a generator of its defining ideal which consists  monomials only.

Comment: This is an example where you get a post marked answer but the answer is not necessarily correct. In algebraic geometry, a monomial curve is exactly how Lonidard describes it. This marked answer is a natural guess from the name of the curve. It could be though that monomial curve is used in other discipline in mathematics (though when one talks about the *defining ideal*, then I am assuming the we are in the context of algebraic geometry).

Answer (score 6):

A *monomial curve* of degree $d$ with parameters $\mathcal{A}=\{0,a_1,\dots,a_c,d\}$ such that $0\lt a_1 \lt \dots \lt a_c \lt d$ is the curve defined by the parametrization

$$\mathbf{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbf{P}^{c+1}$$
$$(s,t)\mapsto(s^d,s^{d-a_1}t^{a_1},s^{d-a_2}t^{a_2},\dots,s^{d-a_c}t^{a_c},t^d)$$